# C Thread Invalid read of size 8 with buffer array

Tags: c, multithreading, valgrind

I have the problem, that when I want to assign my buffer array values, there is a segmentation fault
Code:

```
#define BMPHEADER_SIZE 54
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

// there will be a low level I/O function from the operating system
extern long write(int, const char *, unsigned long);

float zoom      = 1.5;
float quadLimit = 3.0;
char colorLimit = 40;
pthread_mutex_t lock;


typedef struct Complex_s {
    float re;
    float im;
} Complex;

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    int anfang;
    int ende;
    float imageRelation;
    char *blueGreenRed;
    //char *buffer;
    char ***buffer;
}info1;

// bad, but fast !!!
int intFloor(double x) {
    return (int)(x+100000) - 100000;
}

// count chars until \0 or space or "to long"
int len(char * str) {
    int ddorf=0;
    while (str[ddorf] != '\0' && str[ddorf] != ' ' && ddorf != 40225) ++ddorf;
    return ddorf;
}

// read a positive number from a char array
int str2num(char * str) {
    int result = 0;
    int b = 1;
    int l = len(str);
    int i;
    for(i=1; i<l; ++i) b *= 10;
    for(i=0; i<l; ++i) {
        result += b * (int)(str[i] - '0');
        b /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}

void toRGB(int id, char * blueGreenRed) {
    blueGreenRed[0] = 0;
    blueGreenRed[1] = 0;
    blueGreenRed[2] = 0;
    if ( id == colorLimit ) return;

    float hi,q,t,coeff;

    coeff = 7.0 * (id/(float)colorLimit);
    hi = intFloor(coeff);
    t = coeff - hi;
    q = 1 - t;
    if (hi == 0.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = 0;
        blueGreenRed[1] = t*255; //immer mehr green und blau -> dunkelblau zu cyan
        blueGreenRed[0] = t*127 + 128;
    } else if (hi == 1.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = t*255; //immer mehr rot -> cyan zu weiss
        blueGreenRed[1] = 255;
        blueGreenRed[0] = 255;
    } else if (hi == 2.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = 255;
        blueGreenRed[1] = 255;
        blueGreenRed[0] = q*255; // immer weniger blau -> weiss zu gelb
    } else if (hi == 3.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = 255;
        blueGreenRed[1] = q*127 + 128; // immer weniger green -> gelb zu orange
        blueGreenRed[0] = 0;
    } else if (hi == 4.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = q*127 + 128; // orange wird dunkler -> orange zu braun
        blueGreenRed[1] = q*63 + 64;
        blueGreenRed[0] = 0;
    } else if (hi == 5.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = 128;
        blueGreenRed[1] = 64;
        blueGreenRed[0] = t*128; // mehr blau -> braun zu violett
    } else if (hi == 6.0) {
        blueGreenRed[2] = q*128; // weniger rot und green -> violett wird dunkelblau
        blueGreenRed[1] = q*64;
        blueGreenRed[0] = 128;
    }
}

char* calculatePunkt(int x, int y, int width, int height, float imageRelation, char *blueGreenRed) {

    char iterate=0;
    Complex c    = {0,0};
    Complex newz = {0,0};
    Complex z = {0,0};
    float quad=0;

    c.re = zoom * (-1.0 + imageRelation * ( (x-1.0) / (width-1.0)) );
    c.im = zoom * ( 0.5 - (y-1.0) / (height-1.0) );

    // iterate
    for ( iterate=1; iterate < colorLimit && quad < quadLimit; ++iterate ) {
        quad = z.re * z.re + z.im * z.im;

        newz.re = (z.re * z.re) - (z.im * z.im) + c.re;
        newz.im =  z.re * z.im * 2.0            + c.im;

        z = newz;
    }
    toRGB(iterate, blueGreenRed);

    return blueGreenRed;
}   

void *calculateThread(void *arg){

    info1 *abc =(info1*) arg;
    int x, y;
    int anfang = abc->anfang;
    int ende = abc->ende;
    int width = abc->width;
    int height = abc->height;
    float imageRelation = abc->imageRelation;
    char *blueGreenRed = abc->blueGreenRed;
    char ***buffer = abc->buffer;
    //char *buffer = abc->buffer;

    for (y=anfang; y <= ende; ++y) {    

        for (x=1; x <= width; ++x) {


            char* rgb = calculatePunkt(x, y, width, height, imageRelation, blueGreenRed);
            fprintf(stderr, "test, %d\n", anfang);
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            //buffer[(y-1)+(height*(x-1))+(height*width*0)] = rgb[0];
            //buffer[(y-1)+(height*(x-1))+(height*width*1)] = rgb[1];
            //buffer[(y-1)+(height*(x-1))+(height*width*2)] = rgb[2];
            buffer[y-1][x-1][0] = 1;
            buffer[y-1][x-1][1] = 1;
            buffer[y-1][x-1][2] = 1;
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }
    }




}   

int main(int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp) {
    int width  = str2num(argv[1]);
    int height = str2num(argv[2]);
    int anzahl_threads = str2num(argv[3]);

    float imageRelation = (float)width/(float)height;
    int i, j, anfang, ende, y;
    char blueGreenRed[3];
    char buffer[height][width][3];
    for(i=0; i<height; i++){
        for(j=0; j<width; j++){
            buffer[i][j][0]=0;
            buffer[i][j][1]=0;
            buffer[i][j][2]=0;
        }
    }       
    //char *buffer = malloc(height*width*3*sizeof(char));
    //*buffer = (char*){ 0 };


    unsigned char info[BMPHEADER_SIZE] = {
                  //size
        'B','M',  0,0,0,0, 0,0, 0,0, 54,0,0,0,
                  //width  //height
        40,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,  1,0, 24,0,
                  // datasize
        0,0,0,0,  0,0,0,0
    };

    // BMP lines must be of lengths divisible by 4
    char span[4] = "\0\0\0\0";
    int spanBytes = 4 - ((width * 3) % 4);
    if (spanBytes == 4) spanBytes = 0;
    int psize = ((width * 3) + spanBytes) * height;

    *( (int*) &info[2])  = BMPHEADER_SIZE + psize;
    *( (int*) &info[18]) = width;
    *( (int*) &info[22]) = height;
    *( (int*) &info[34]) = psize;

    write(1, (char *) info, BMPHEADER_SIZE);

    struct timeval start, end;
    gettimeofday(&start, 0);
    int interval = height/anzahl_threads;

    info1 *abc = malloc(anzahl_threads*sizeof(info1));;

    pthread_t *thread = malloc(anzahl_threads*sizeof(pthread_t));

    if(pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL)){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error initializing mutex\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for(i=0; i<anzahl_threads; i++){

        (abc+i)->width = width;
        (abc+i)->height = height;
        (abc+i)->imageRelation = imageRelation;
        (abc+i)->blueGreenRed = blueGreenRed;
        (abc+i)->buffer = ***buffer;
        //abc->buffer = *buffer;
        anfang = 1+(i*interval);
        (abc+i)->anfang = anfang;
        if(i<(anzahl_threads-1)){
            ende = (i*interval)+interval;
        }
        else{
            ende = height;
        }
        (abc+i)->ende = ende;       
        if (pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, calculateThread, (void*)(abc+i))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error creating thread\n");
            return 1;
        }

    }   

    for(i=0; i<anzahl_threads; i++){
        if (pthread_join(thread[i], NULL)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error joining thread\n");
            return 2;
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    for(y=1; y<=height; ++y){
        // BMP lines must be of lengths divisible by 4
        write(1, span, spanBytes);
    }   
    write(1, buffer, height*width*3);
    //free(buffer);
    free(thread);
    free(abc);



    gettimeofday(&end, 0);

    unsigned long timediff = ((end.tv_sec*1000000)+end.tv_usec) - ((start.tv_sec*1000000)+start.tv_usec);
    fprintf(stderr, "Gesamtzeit in Mikrosek.: %lu\n", timediff);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind:

```
==28366== Thread 2:
==28366== Invalid read of size 8
==28366==    at 0x401115: calculateThread (in /home/nilskk/Schreibtisch/Betriebssysteme/Abgabe2/Aufgabe1/mandel1)
==28366==    by 0x4E3F183: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==28366==    by 0x514F37C: clone (clone.S:111)
==28366==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==28366== 
==28366== 
==28366== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==28366==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0
==28366==    at 0x401115: calculateThread (in /home/nilskk/Schreibtisch/Betriebssysteme/Abgabe2/Aufgabe1/mandel1)
==28366==    by 0x4E3F183: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==28366==    by 0x514F37C: clone (clone.S:111)
==28366==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==28366==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==28366==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==28366==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==28366==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--28366-- REDIR: 0x50d7d00 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2bd80 (free)
==28366== 
==28366== HEAP SUMMARY:
==28366==     in use at exit: 640 bytes in 4 blocks
==28366==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 0 frees, 640 bytes allocated
==28366== 
==28366== Searching for pointers to 4 not-freed blocks
==28366== Checked 16,869,264 bytes
==28366== 
==28366== Thread 1:
==28366== 544 bytes in 2 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 3 of 3
==28366==    at 0x4C2CC70: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==28366==    by 0x4012E14: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:296)
==28366==    by 0x4012E14: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:460)
==28366==    by 0x4E3FD92: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:589)
==28366==    by 0x4E3FD92: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:500)
==28366==    by 0x40187E: main (in /home/nilskk/Schreibtisch/Betriebssysteme/Abgabe2/Aufgabe1/mandel1)
==28366== 
==28366== LEAK SUMMARY:
==28366==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28366==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28366==      possibly lost: 544 bytes in 2 blocks
==28366==    still reachable: 96 bytes in 2 blocks
==28366==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==28366== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==28366== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==28366== 
==28366== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==28366== 
==28366== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
==28366== Thread 2:
==28366== Invalid read of size 8
==28366==    at 0x401115: calculateThread (in /home/nilskk/Schreibtisch/Betriebssysteme/Abgabe2/Aufgabe1/mandel1)
==28366==    by 0x4E3F183: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
==28366==    by 0x514F37C: clone (clone.S:111)
==28366==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==28366== 
==28366== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

When I comment the buffer assignment in the thread function, it works. So it has to do something with the buffer, but I don't see the mistake.

Comment: And if you build with debug information (add the `-g` flag to GCC when building) then on what *line* in your does Valgrind say the problem occur?

Comment: Pointers and arrays are different. You can't use a `char ***` to access the elements of `char buffer[height][width][3]`.

Comment: The problem occurs in the line with `buffer[y-1][x-1][0]=1`

Comment: How can I access the array in the struct?

Comment: Try changing `char ***buffer` to `void *buffer` in `info1`, and changing `char ***buffer` to `char (*buffer)[width][3]` in `calculateThread`.

Comment: note: the `write()` function declaration is incorporated by: `#include <unistd.h>`

Comment: the function: `void *calculateThread(void *arg)` states that it will return a `void*` but the function actually just runs off the end of the function:  Since this is a 'thread' function, it should end with something similar to: int status=0; pthread_exit( &status );`

Comment: the posted code is missing `#include <stdlib.h>` for th prototype for `free()`, `malloc()`

Comment: when writing a literal, if written without a trailing `f`, then it is seen as a `double` rather than a `float`.  While 'implicit conversion' will save you (usually), it is much better to include the trailing `f` so no conversion is needed

Comment: in the `main()` function, never access beyond `argv[0]` without first checking `argc` to verify the expected command line parameters were actually entered by the user.  Otherwise seg fault events will occur.  When the expected command line parameters were not entered, then output a `USAGE` message to `stderr` and exit the program.  Note: the third parameter is no longer valid.  If you need to access the environment variables, use `getenv()`

Comment: the function: `len()` should (probably) be replaced with calling: `strlen()`, which is prototyped in the `string.h` header file

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the posted code is assuming that a `int` size is 4 bytes.  This assumption is only 'usually' correct when the underlying computer architecture is 32bits.  I.E. this fails on 64bit architectures and any architecture that is less than 32 bits

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  (for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  I also use: `-Wconversion -std=gnu11` )

Comment: the posted code contains (many) 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 2, 4,18, 22, 34, and many others. 'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or an `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then using those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: regarding: `write(1, buffer, height*width*3);`  unless the `width` has been 'adjusted' to reflect the required 'multiple of 4' bytes, this will fail to write the whole buffer of pixel data

Comment: regarding: `unsigned long timediff = ((end.tv_sec*1000000)+end.tv_usec) - ((start.tv_sec*1000000)+start.tv_usec);`  the struct tv fields are unsigned values.  multiplying them by the signed value `1000000` results in signed values  subtracting results in a signed value which is being converted to a unsigned value.  Depending on your compiler and the actual values, the result can be incorrect

Answer (score 1):

This line of code is obviously wrong. The type on the left hand side is a `char ***` and you're assigning to it a `char`, with specifically the value of `0` as that is how you initialise `buffer` at the top of `main`

```
(abc+i)->buffer = ***buffer;
```

ideally you want it to be

```
(abc+i)->buffer = buffer;
```

but that won't work as `buffer` is a 3 dimensional array rather than a `char ***` and they're not equivalent.

You could either create `buffer` as a `char ***` by allocating the various levels or since each thread is only accessing a subset of `buffer` you could make it a global variable?

Comment: But how do I create buffer as global variable, if I don't know height and width? Maybe I'm missing something

Comment: No, I guess you can't have it as a global with the way you're declaring it currently.

Comment: I did it now global and initialized it with malloc. Now it finally works. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @NKK It's best to avoid global variables where possible.

Comment: The dynamic approach creating a jagged array (which in fact is many linked arrays) is an expensive and quite complicated solution, which probably only really make sense for huge  values of `height` and `width`. For smaller ones better go for the approach provided *Ian* in his answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/44029056/694576

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access the data via a pointer to pointer to pointer to `char` (`char ***`), but the data is actually an array [`height`] of array [`width`] of array [3] of `char` (`char [height][width][3]`). A pointer to the first element of this array is a pointer to an array [`width`] of array [3] of `char` (`char (*)[width][3]`). Since `width` and `height` are variable, the `info1` type cannot contain a member `buffer` of type `char (*)[width][3]`, so the easiest thing to do is to declare it as a `void *`:

```
typedef struct {
    ...
    void *buffer;
    ...
} info1;
```

In function `calculateThread`, the original `width` value is available, so you can declare local variable `buffer` with the correct type and initialize it:

```
    char (*buffer)[width][3] = abc->buffer;
```

In function `main`, the assignment `(abc+i)->buffer = ***buffer;` is obviously incorrect as `***buffer` is of type `char`. You want a pointer to the start of the buffer contents, which is just `buffer`, so change that to:

```
            (abc+i)->buffer = buffer;
```